# Prove the continuous image of a closed bounded interval is compact using elementary real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Using elementary real analysis (only), prove the continuous image of a closed bounded interval is compact.  *Compact* is defined as: every sequence has a subsequence converging to a member of the set (from https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_hw_final.pdf ).

**Lemma:** A closed bounded interval is compact.

**Proof of Lemma:** By Bolzano-Weierstrass, any sequence $x_n$ in interval $[a, b]$ has a subsequence which converges; call its limit $c$.  $c$ cannot be greater than $b$, for if it were, the subsequence would have an element $y$ such that  $y \geq \frac{b+c}{2} > b$.  Similarly, $c$ is not less than $a$.  QED.

**Main Proof:** Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$.
Since a continuous function takes on a max and min on a closed set, $f([a,b])$ has max $m$ and min $n$, and $y \in f([a,b]) \implies n \leq y \leq m$.  By IVT, $n \leq y \leq m \implies y \in f([a,b])$.  Thus, $f([a,b]) = [n, m]$, and, by the lemma, is compact.

Is this proof correct? Can it be simplified (without introducing results from topology)? Can the exposition be improved?

Comment: It's a common mistake to think that a closed interval needs to be finite. $[0,\infty)$ or $\Bbb R$ are also closed intervals.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: It is a matter of definition.

Comment: It would be nice to use the definition of compactness to prove more generally that if $A$ is compact then $f(A) $ is compact.

Comment: Within the constraints given, it is a very nice proof. I see little about it that could be improved, other than not abbreviating, and relying more on words than symbology, both of which make the proof a bit harder to read for readers not currently deeply involved with this branch of mathematics. But these are minor things.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Done! Please comment on the expanded proof (below).

Comment: Let $(x_j)_j$ be a sequence in $[a,b].$ Let $[a_1,b_1]=[a,b].$ If $\{j:x_j\in [a_n,(a_n+b_n)/2]\}$ is infinite then let $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]=[a_n,(a_n+b_n)/2].$ If not then let  $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]=[(a_n+b_n)/2,b_n]. $ Now let $f(1)=1$. Let $f(n+1)$ be the least (or any) $ j$ such that $j>f(n)$ and $x_j\in  [a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]. $ Then $f$ is strictly increasing. And $(x_{f(n)})_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, because  |$x_n-x_{n+1}|\le (b-a)2^{1-n}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paramanand Singh suggested, I'm expanding this to: Prove the continuous image of compact set $S$  is compact.

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence in $f(S)$.  We will show that $\{y_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$ which converges to a limit $y \in f(S)$, making $f(S)$ compact.

Clearly, there exists a corresponding sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $S$ such that for all $n$, $f(x_n) = y_n$.  Since $S$ is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ which converges to a limit in $S$ which we'll call $x$.  By definition, $f(x) \in f(S)$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k}$.  QED.

Please comment on the accuracy, rigor, and exposition of this proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me.